# jQuery to parse our a part of a url path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I need to parse long urls and set a variable (category) equal to one of the `/folders/` in the path.

For example, a url that is

`http://example.com/community/home/whatever.html`

I need to set the variable equal to whatever folder path comes after `/home/` in that url.

I've got this to alert me with what comes after /community/, but then the url turns to NaN and the link doesnt work. I think I'm not on the right track.

```
if ($(this.href*='http://example.com/community/')){

  var category = url.split("community/");

  alert(category[category.length - 1]);

}
```

Thoughts?

TIA.

Comment: sorry, I need to set the variable equal to whatever folder path comes after /community/ in that url.

Comment: I'm not getting that `this.href*=` thing at all.  What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: jquery selector for if this href attribute contains http://example.com/community/

Comment: As the OP asked, He just has the IDEA of doing thing. So we have to give his idea an implementations.

Comment: I think `$(this.href*='http://example.com/community/')` is suppose to be `$('[href*="http://example.com/community/"]')`... /me shrugs

Comment: oops that did not fix my syntax problem.

Comment: You may want to check out http://millermedeiros.github.com/crossroads.js/ for Javascript-based routing techniques

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch everything after the "/community/" with a regular expression:

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/community/whatever";
var category = "";
var matches = url.match(/\/community\/(.*)$/);
if (matches) {
    category = matches[1];   // "whatever"
}
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/BL4jm/

If you want to get only the next path segment after community and nothing after that segment, then you could use this:

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/community/whatever/more";
var category = "";
var matches = url.match(/\/community\/([^\/]+)/);
if (matches) {
    category = matches[1];    // "whatever"
} else {
    // no match for the category
}
```

Workikng example of this one here:http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/vrvbT/

Comment: that works, but what if i were to want to return whatever, not whatever/asdf: http://jsfiddle.net/BL4jm/2/ – ben 2 mins ago edit

Comment: @ben - I updated my answer with a 2nd option to get only the "whatever" part.

Comment: this doesn't help me with only doing this IF the string in the href matches that pattern, but i've got something that will work by setting category = "Doesn't Match", and then overwriting it if it matches. thanks mate!

Comment: @ben - If you want to execute code when it doesn't match, then just put an else on the end of the if.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `this.href*=` you're doing **multiplication**, and that's why you're getting not-a-number. It multiplies `this.href` by the string and assigns that to `href`.

If you mean to test whether the url starts with that string you can do it like this, no need for jQuery:

```
var start = 'http://example.com/community/';
if (url.substring(0, start.length) === start)){
  var category = url.split("community/");
  var lastPart = category[category.length - 1];
  return lastPart.split("/")[0];
}
```

Comment: @ben: just split again by "/" and return the first result. See my answer.