# Get last string from URL with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to get the last string from a URL for example...

```
http://www.mywebsite/blog/this-post
```

I want to use jQuery to get 'this-post'
Ive the following...

```
$('img.gigthumb').each(function(){
    var foo = $(this).parent().attr('href').split('/');
    $(this).attr('src','/lic/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/'+foo[1]+'.jpg');
})
```

only it doesn't work and I presume thats because I have multiple '/' within the URL, any idea how to target just the last?

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery to parse our a part of a url path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894093/jquery-to-parse-our-a-part-of-a-url-path)

Comment: Hello, I just think that is appropriated to make you know about the performance of `.pop()` vs `arr[arr.length-1]` http://jsperf.com/pop-vs-arr-length-1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is precisely what [`.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) is made for:

```
$('img.gigthumb').each(function(){
    var foo = $(this).parent().attr('href').split('/').pop();
    $(this).attr('src','/lic/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/' + foo + '.jpg');
});
```

Comment: I have my doubts about using `.pop()` instead of just `foo[foo.length-1]`

Comment: @ajax333221 - Care to share with the class?

Comment: @JosephSilber , I am not English speaker, I googgled what you said and still don't know what you meant. Please say it in other words

Comment: @ajax333221 - Why do you have your doubts? What's wrong with using `.pop()`? Why is `foo[foo.length-1]` better than `.pop()`?

Comment: @JosephSilber , `.pop()` it is doing unnecessary work by removing the last item on the array, while `arr[arr.lenght-1]` isn't. I compared the performance here http://jsperf.com/pop-vs-arr-length-1

Comment: @ajax333221 - While you're right that `.pop()` is a tad slower, I still prefer it for its legibility. If that loop will be running over a vast amount of elements I would switch it out...

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the element with index 1 of `foo`, but the last one:

```
$(this).attr('src','/lic/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/'+foo[foo.length-1]+'.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

Splitting with "/" will give you the array:

```
foo[0] = "http:"
foo[1] = ""
foo[2] = "www.mywebsite"
foo[3] = "blog"
foo[4] = "this-post"
```

If you want to get the last item regardless of the size of the array do:

```
foo[foo.length - 1]
```

or as Joseph mentioned: `foo.pop()`

Comment: +1 `.pop()` is slower because it is modifying the array (by removing the last item). here are is the proof http://jsperf.com/pop-vs-arr-length-1

Answer (score 0):

Following your example you need the last part of the splits:

```
$('img.gigthumb').each(function(){
    var foo = $(this).parent().attr('href').split('/');
    var last = foo.length - 1;
    $(this).attr('src','/lic/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/'+foo[last]+'.jpg');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = $(this).parent().attr('href').replace(/^.*\\/, '');
```